# CSS div size and overlap concerns

Tags: css, html

I am trying to help a graphic designer with her website http://designingforgood.tumblr.com/

She wanted the SnapWidget which is the grid of six photos on the bottom left so I placed it there. My concern is that it gets cut off in smaller windows which may mean that on smaller screens it will also not be displayed properly.

Also, in different browsers the distance from the blue box above the photo grid changes. It looks further away in firefox than in chrome. I worry that in some other browser it may even end up overlapping.

I searched for an answer on w3schools but didn't find what I was looking for. I also searched for similar questions here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Why do you use iframe for the thumbnails?

Answer (score 0):

Well you have inline styles on the `div` containing your photos that is settings its `position` as `fixed`. Your sidebar is also set to `fixed`. The only way to make sure that section is scrollable is by removing both of those values and fixing it up from there.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove position fixed from all divs inside the sidebar.
2. Wrap both sidebar and thumbnails inside another div and give an id `sidebar-container` to this div. You should end up with this main structure for your sidebar:

   `<div id="sidebar-container">

     <div id="blue-box">...</div>

     <div id="photo-grid">...</div>

   </div>`
3. Fix any css problems you have. Make sure website looks good in both situations, when sidebar has fixed position and when it hasn't. Maybe you want to float the sidebar to work well in both cases.
4. Use jQuery (I see you load it anyways) to determine if the height of the `#sidebar-container` is less than the height of the window and only then, we add `position:fixed;`.

The jQuery code might be like this:

```
function checkHeight() {
  var sidebarHeight = jQuery("#sidebar-container").height();
  var windowHeight = jQuery(window).height();

  if( sidebarHeight <= windowHeight ) {
    jQuery("#sidebar-container").css({ 'position' : 'fixed' });
  } else {
    jQuery("#sidebar-container").removeAttr("style");
  }
}

jQuery(document).ready(checkHeight);
jQuery(window).resize(checkHeight);
```

So, users with big screens will benefit from the fixed sidebar and users with small screens will have the ability to view the whole sidebar by scrolling down.